# Proof for differential equality

Tags: calculus

In Schaum Outline (Lagrangian dynamics) on page 23 it makes the following equality, with x a function of t and $\dot{x}$ being the first derivative of x relative to t etc.:

$$\ddot{x}dx = \dot{x}d\dot{x}\tag{1}$$

I guessed an outline of what is probably being done is something like :

$$\ddot{x}dx = \frac {d \dot{x}}{dt} dx = d\dot{x}\frac {dx}{dt} = \dot{x}d\dot{x}\tag{2}$$

There look to be several issues with doing this movement of $\normalsize dt$ from under $d\dot{x}$ to being under $\normalsize dx$ in equation (2), so I was wondering if anyone knows of a formal proof of the above equalities with the limits etc. being properly addressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a more formal way to show the equation, and perhaps it's what the book had in mind, would be to use the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) and then multiply by $dx$ on both sides. In particular, you would get

$$\ddot{x} = \frac{d\dot{x}}{dt} = \frac{d\dot{x}}{dx}\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right) = \frac{d\dot{x}}{dx}(\dot{x}) \implies \ddot{x}dx = \dot{x}d\dot{x} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$